# Segmentation Fault Using MySQL PDO and "SHOW CREATE TABLE .." Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some large MRG_MyISAM tables and I would like to select the tablenames of the origin-tables. On my local machine it works well by selecting the create-statement via

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <merge-tablename>
```

On my remote machine I get an errormessage `Segmentation Fault`.

I tested various cases and the script behaves very strange on my remote server. It sometimes works well if I prepend an useless query like:

```
$pdoStatement = $objPDO->query("SELECT 1"); //useless query
$pdoStatement = $objPDO->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $seTableName");
```

But this is not really a solution.

Does someone know this kind of problem or does anyone know an alternative way to get the names of the origin-tables of a MRG_MyISAM-table?